# execvp with a spaces in the path

Tags: macos, unix, escaping, execvp

I have a cpp file that calls execvp() with the 1st parameter "/Library/Application Support/myapp/myapp.app"

It does not work, I also tried adding "\" before the space.

How can I make this work?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly does not work? E.g., what error code do you get?

Comment: don't you get an error message some place? Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a directory (app bundle), not an executable. You'll have to either start the actual executable (usually in the `Contents/MacOS` directory of the bundle) or exec `open` with the path to the app.

Comment: That's the traditional way to open an application bundled in a .app folder but what if the application itself wants to exec another binary in the bundle folders ?